# Java reflection: how get value of Field as Arraylist<>

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have a Menu object.

this has an `Arrraylist<MenuItemImpl>` to "mItems" name. this is hide.

(`MenuItemImpl`) is a hide & protected class.
See class ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.holoeverywhere/library/1.5.0/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/MenuBuilder.java#MenuBuilder.0mActionItems))

Now ,how i can get this arraylist.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    { 

      List<Field> list = getAllFields(menu);
      for(Field f: list)
      {
          if(f.getName().equals("mItems"))
           {
             f.setAccessible(true);
             return f.get( /* here */ );   // <<--- I use new Arraylist<Object> , but get exception
           }
       }
   }

public static List<Field> getAllFields(Object obj)
    {
        List<Field> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.addAll(Arrays.asList(obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));
    if (obj.getClass().getSuperclass() != null)
    {
        res.addAll(Arrays.asList(obj.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields()));
    }

    return res;
}
```

in f.get() I use `new Arraylist<Object>` , but get exception

Please help me.Tanks

Answer (score 1):

oh, I get my answer.

```
for(Field f: list)
      {
          if(f.getName().equals("mItems"))
           {
             f.setAccessible(true);
             return f.get(menu);
           }
       }
```